# navbar hide text in bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the problem that hides the text behind the bar, as in the image below.

[image: Imagen]

code
    
      
        
          
            Toggle navigation
            
            
            
          
          MegaMenu

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse js-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span></a>

        </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        <!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </nav>
    </div>
```

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Update the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess, you have a `navbar-fixed-top` class on your navbar.

The fixed navbar has a position on fixed, which overlays any element.

The navbar itself has a width of 50 pixels.

What I tend to do in my applications with fixed BS navbar is the following:

```
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Doesn't need to be the body, but the essential idea is to wrap your content and push it down 50px.

## Edit

OP added his code and though the navbar is not `navbar-fixed-top`, the problem is the same.

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein If this worked for you, please accept this as the answer. It encourages us to continue helping others.